# javascript timer counting very fast as time passes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a counter which reset in specific interval of time. I wrote this code. When I refresh the page it is executing perfectly. But as time passes the timer goes really fast, skipping seconds. Any idea why this is happening.

```
function countdown_new() {

    window.setInterval(function () {
        var timeCounter = $("b[id=show-time]").html();
        var updateTime = eval(timeCounter) - eval(1);
        $("b[id=show-time]").html(updateTime);

        if (updateTime == 0) {
            //window.location = ("ajax_chart.php");
            $("b[id=show-time]").html(5);
            clearInterval(countdown_new());
            // countdown_new();
            //my_ajax();
        }
    }, 1000);

}


window.setInterval(function () {
    countdown_new();
}, 5000)
```

HTML 
    
        Coundown in 5 seconds

Comment: this is a quite strange  `$("b[id=show-time]")` selector

Comment: I suggest you step back from your current task and work through some JavaScript tutorials. You don't want or need to use `eval` for basic math, for instance, or for type conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling window.setInterval(), which schedules a function call to countdown_new() ever 5 seconds without stop.

Compounding the problem, you are calling countdown_new() again inside your clear interval.

You need to call setInterval just once to continuously execute a function every 5 seconds.

If you want to cancel an interval timer, you need do to this:

```
var intervalObj = setInterval(function() { ... }, 5000);
clearInterval(intervalObj);
```

Comment: See Rory's answer -- based on the OP's code, it looks like they want to wait five seconds, then update every second. This would update every five seconds.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you are not clearing the previous timer before starting a new one, so you start a new one for each iteration. To clear the timer you should save a reference to it, and pass that to `clearInterval`, not a function reference.

Also, note that your pattern of using multiple intervals for different operations can lead to overlap (where two intervals are acting at the same time and cause odd behaviour). Instead, use `setTimeout` for the initial 5 second delay and then chain further calls to stop this overlap.

Try this:

```
var timer;
function countdown_new() {
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        var $showTime = $("#show-time")
        var updateTime = parseInt($showTime.text(), 10) - 1;
        $showTime.html(updateTime);

        if (updateTime == 0) {
            $showTime.html('5');
            clearInterval(timer);
            setTimeout(countdown_new, 5000);
        }
    }, 1000);    
}

setTimeout(countdown_new, 5000);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/15421b44/)

Note that you should use the `#` selector to select an element by its `id` attribute, and you should never use `eval` - especially not for type coercion. To convert a value to an integer use `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes clearinterval does the trick.

```
       function countdown_new(){

     t =  window.setInterval(function() {
                var timeCounter = $("b[id=show-time]").html();
                var updateTime = eval(timeCounter)- eval(1);
                $("b[id=show-time]").html(updateTime);

                if(updateTime == 0){
                    //window.location = ("ajax_chart.php");
                    $("b[id=show-time]").html(5);
                    clearInterval(t);
                   // countdown_new();
                    my_ajax();
                }
            }, 1000);

    }
```